# Ignore or exclude code in external libraries with gcov

Tags: c++, gcov, boost-range

I am working on a project which uses a couple of boost libraries. When looking at our test reports, we have seen that test coverage information sometimes does fit to our source code. I was able to track it down to boost::range. I think it is because of some static initialization inside the library, although I cannot say anything more specific.

Basically, if you compile the following code with `gcc --coverage`, run it and print the coverage report with `gcov -b`, there will be four additional branches and an additional line, which I would like to ignore.

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>

int foo(int x)
{
    return x+1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return foo(argc);
}
```

The coverage report is:
Lines executed:100.00% of 5
Branches executed:100.00% of 4
Taken at least once:50.00% of 4
Calls executed:100.00% of 2
Creating 'test_gcov.cpp.gcov'

I guess that the count of 5 lines comes from the two function signatures, the function bodies and one additional line in the boost::range library. I don't know where exactly, but the generated gcov-file shows that some static initialization is going on, so I guess that is where the branches are located.

I would like to know if there is a way to tell gcov to ignore any code in the boost namespace, or any other means.

Comment: Were you able to fond out answer for your problem? I am solvin a similar one and any hints would be appreciated. :)

Comment: @Petr Sorry, I couldn't find the reason quickly and then had to turn to some other issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `--remove` or `-r` flag to ignore files from external libraries.  For example:

```
lcov -c -d <build_dir> -o <output_trace_file>
lcov -r <output_trace_file> "/usr*" -o <output_trace_file>
```

You can replace `"/usr*"` with whatever pattern you're trying to remove.

The [blog post here](https://qiaomuf.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/use-gcov-and-lcov-to-know-your-test-coverage/) gives a good example of how to use that flag (and covers the whole `lcov` process, start to finish.)